# Is it possible to identify an element only knowing part of its name?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, pageobjects

I'm trying to identify `<div>` elements with ids that are dynamically generated. I want to be able to grab the element using the text identifier.

I don't want to have to know what the exact name is. For example, if there was a div tag containing "This is a div text", I would want to grab that with `@browser.div(:text => 'div text')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do partial matching of an element's property.

For example, in your situation, you can do:

```
@browser.div(:text => /div text/)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to pass a variable into the regex? `def find_portlet (app_name)
    @browser.div(:text => /app_name/)
  end`

Comment: Then you could do `@browser.div(:text => /#{app_name}/)`

Comment: Thanks! I had just found that. Regex is quite new to me.